# Conflicting reports of Hand Baggage allowance on British Airways (23 vs 7 kilos)

Tags: luggage, british-airways

I'm going for a BA International Flight tomorrow (DEL - LR - YYZ). I remember reading that BA allows 7 kilograms in cabin luggage/carry-on, and it still says so on the e-Ticket which I got from the website I booked the ticket from.

However, when I go into "Manage my Booking" on BA's official website it states that my Handbag and Cabin Suitcase can be **23 kilos each.** Keep in mind that this is a full ticket, and I am allowed 2 pieces of check-in baggage already (which are also, funnily enough, at 23 Kgs each).

Link on BA's official website: https://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/baggage-essentials/hand-baggage-allowances

1. Am I missing something here? Does this mean that I can *theoretically* carry 23*4 = 92 kilos of luggage?
2. Why is this limit so high? I'm fairly certain most suitcases that size aren't designed to carry that weight.
3. In general, should we follow the guidelines given on the websites of the airline, or the information given on the websites we booked the tickets from? In other words, is it possible that my ticket is somehow *different* from a normal ticket because I bought it from an external agency?

Apologies for any incompetency seeping through this question, but this is something that has genuinely bewildered me.

Additional Sources:
This is another link at Skyscanner: https://www.skyscanner.net/news/tips/beat-the-british-airways-cabin-baggage-rules

---

I feel like there is no reason to doubt this, as the comments say. Even if I did, I haven't found a *single* source other than my e-ticket which says another limit, so I don't even know what limit I should follow. I'll answer this after I've taken the flight and see how it goes.

Comment: Screenshot this (blank out any personal details). I suspect you are mistaken. There is no airline which would allow such. The most lenient I am aware has no explicit limits except "you must be able to lift your suitcase above your head unaided".

Comment: Seems to be a mistake on BA website. It does say 23kg but also "you must be able to place the bag in overhead locker".

Comment: If we consider this a snatch which is the closest weightlifghting exercise, most women wouldn't be able to: https://strengthlevel.com/strength-standards/snatch/kg https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Percentage-of-women-classified-as-underweight-55kg-normal-weight-55-75kg_fig2_224770690

Comment: @chx give me a minute. And I don't see how I'm making a mistake, since this is the official website, so if anything, it's a glitch on BA's side.

Comment: I’d go with the e-ticket details. BA has had some very odd systems-related errors recently eg yesterday’s email flight cancellation advice fiasco.

Comment: It could be a mistake. Or it could be that they know cabin luggage is almost never weighed so they dispensed with the earlier fictional limit. They do stipulate that you must be able to lift it yourself and that exceeding the weight or size limit, the luggage will count towards your hold luggage allowance. I guess it could theoretically be possible to carry 92 kg if you put gold or something dense like that in a laptop bag.

Comment: @Traveller but this can't be something they mess up on my ticket AND their own website? They even have graphics on their website with the number 23Kg on it. I've also linked a Skyscanner article.

Comment: @Traveller I'm from India, and the e-ticket websites aren't really too trustworthy IMO. They actually say I can only check-in one luggage (when it's 2), and they also sent me my password in plaintext when I asked to reset it, but that's for another SE.

Comment: Are both flights also operated by BA, or is one of them a codeshare? AFAIK, in case of a codeshare the rules of the operating airline apply.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify questions in comments. Put on hold for now.